# No whitespace for authors with two given names

Tags: spacing, bibtex, author

I am using bibtex and discovered (days before I have to submit the thesis) a problem.

An example would be this:

Document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\begin{document}
Single name \cite{single}.
Double name \cite{double}.
\bibliographystyle{abbrvdin}
\bibliography{bibexp}
\end{document}
```

Bibexp.bib:

```
@article{double,
    title = {Title of the paper},
    journal = {Journal of WTF},
    author = {First, A. and Second, A. A.},
    year = {2019}
}
@article{single,
    title = {Title of the paper},
    journal = {Journal of WTF},
    author = {First, A. and Second, A.},
    year = {2019}
}
```

I am getting this:
[image]

I know I can delete the whitespace between the authors and the ";" by using this method [How to “delete” space between Author and semicolon in bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468119/how-to-delete-space-between-author-and-semicolon-in-bibtex?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C36.8697)

but with my limited tex knowledge, I couldn't find a way to handle the inconsistency for the whitespace before the ": Title of the paper"
Only if the last author has two given names there is no whitespace, if he has one given name there is whitespace.

Is there a quick fix (other than to change to biblatex for which I do not have the time...)? Thank you very much in advance and apologies if the question was already answered.

Comment: Welcome ygody! I'm afraid this is how `abbrvdin` was designed - I do not know why but the examples here https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-din1505-abbrvdin/ work like yours. So not you fault here and not much you can do about. You may stay with it, find a better style or manipulate (copy) the `abbrvdin.bst` to your needs if you know how to _program_ in BST. Unfortunately I don't. Sorry I can't be of more help ...